# Counter intuitive in AUPRC and Recall and Precision and F1 for imbalanced dataset

Tags: unbalanced-classes

I would like to ask for some details explanation on comparing several classifiers for imbalanced dataset using the following metrics:

- Area under the ROC curve, AUC
- Area under the Precision-Recall curve, AUPRC
- Recall
- Precision
- F1 Score

As my data are highly imbalanced, minority class ~0.02%, I don't focus much on the AUC as it could not provide a full picture. I include AUPRC, Recall, Precision, and F1. I read a comparison of AUC and AUPRC [here](https://www.andybeger.com/2015/03/16/precision-recall-curves/).

For example in the below Table (bold values are the best ones):
    \begin{array}{lccccc|c}
 & AUC & AUPRC & Recall & Precison & F1 & Rank\\
 \hline
   C1  & 0.933 & 0.745 & 0.581 & \textbf{0.908} & 0.680 & 3.8\\
   C2   & \textbf{0.949} & \textbf{0.750} & 0.882 & 0.067 & 0.123 & 3.2\\
   C3 & 0.944 & 0.750 & 0.876 & 0.062 & 0.113 & 4.4\\
   C4 & 0.941 & 0.730 & \textbf{0.901} & 0.018 & 0.035 & 5.2\\
   C5   & 0.940 & 0.637 & 0.502 & 0.777 & 0.501 & 5.6 \\
   C6  & 0.901 & 0.631 & 0.564 & 0.643 & 0.444 & 6.4 \\
   C7  & 0.942 & 0.723 & 0.803 & 0.500 & 0.583 & 4.2\\
   C8 & 0.948 & 0.717 & 0.642 & 0.852 & \textbf{0.710} & 3.2\\
   \hline
  \end{array}

What I don't really get is as I focus on positive samples detection rate, I find C5,6,7,8 are more balancing toward Recall and Precision and hence, result in better F1. However, for them, the AUPRCs are lower compared with C1,2,3,4.

I compute AUPRC via Average Precision using scikit-learn. The final rank column is the average rank across all metrics.

Comment: What exactly is your question?